# Create Application Setup

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, installation

I want to create an application setup, I'm using Advanced Installer. I want to build a setup that will install SQL Server 2008 and attach a `.mdf` file and also install the .net Framework 3.5 if does not exist on the machine.

How can I do this?

Comment: The recommended way is to define these things (.NET 3.5, SQL Server 2008) as **pre-requisites** and make the user install them ahead of time or as part of your install, by downloading them from the vendor's site. Microsoft doesn't provide a means to actually *include* those items into your own installer itself (for legal and other reasons). See: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/prerequisites.html

Comment: But I want to include those files in my application setup because installing sql server 2008 is not that easy. Some installer like inFlow inventory install sql server 2008 R2 if not existing on the machine

Comment: There is a tutorial that shows how to install SQL Server Express http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/howto-install-sql-server-express.html